# Python Password Checker Incorrect Output

Tags: python

I am trying to Implement the function _isValid() in password_checker.py that returns True if the given password
string meets the following requirements, and False otherwise:

- Is at least eight characters long
- Contains at least one digit (0-9)
- Contains at least one uppercase letter
- Contains at least one lowercase letter
- Contains at least one character that is neither a letter nor a number

Here is my code:

```
import stdio
import sys


# Entry point
def main():
    pwd = sys.argv[1]
    stdio.writeln(_isValid(pwd))


# Returns True if pwd is a valid password, and False otherwise.
def _isValid(pwd):
    check1 = False  # length flag
    check2 = False  # digit flag
    check3 = False  # upper case flag
    check4 = False  # lower case flag
    check5 = False  # alphanumeric flag

    # If pwd is long enough, set corresponding flag to True.
    if len(pwd) >= 8:
        check1 = True

    for c in pwd:
        # For each character c in pwd...

        if c.isdigit():
            # If c is a digit, set corresponding flag to True.
            check2 = True
        elif c.isupper():
            # If c is in upper case, set corresponding flag to True.
            check3 = True
        elif c.islower():
            # If c is in lower case, set corresponding flag to True.
            check4 = True
        elif c.isalnum():
            # If c is not alphanumeric, set corresponding flag to True.
            check5 = True

    # Return True if all flags are True, and False otherwise.
    if check1 and check2 and check3 and check4 and check5:
        return True
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I don't get the correct output and can't seem to figure out why

Comment: If you use `elif`, if any of the `if` condition satisfies, then the others will not be checked. So change all your `elif` to `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer in your own comment:

```
elif c.isalnum():
   # If c is not alphanumeric, set corresponding flag to True.
```

Therefore this should be:

```
elif not c.isalnum():
```